# using Jinja to access dictionary in for loop

Tags: html, dictionary, jinja2

I have a `for` loop that needs multiple outcomes from a dictionary.  So I have a list of dictionaries like `{'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3 }` and I have a loop in my HTML like:

```
{% for d in dictionary_list %}

{{d['a']}}

{{d['b']}}

{{d['c']))

{% endfor %}
```

How can I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

How about using the dot notation instead?

```
dl = [{'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3 }, {'a':4, 'b':5, 'c':6 }]
t = Template("""
{% for d in dictionary_list %}
 {{ d.a }}
 {{ d.b }}
 {{ d.c }}
{% endfor %}
""")
t.render(dictionary_list=dl)
```

Comment: the main issue is I need all three in the same loop, is there a way to do that?  Like if I wanted all three in a sentence.

Comment: Thanks, I misunderstood.  You basically had things right.  This amended example should work.  Just pass the list in as a variable when rendering the template.  Let me know if this answers your question.

Comment: thanks i'll try it out and let you know if that fixed it!

Comment: I'm getting this error: Could not parse the remainder: '['a']' from 'd['a']'

Comment: The bracket notation works for me, but there is also a dot notation.  See if that works.  I amended the answer again.